# Mongo aggregation framework: finding minimum value within projected values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate a collection of recipes. Each recipe in the collection has a `calories` field that is the amount of calories in one serving. I need to find recipes with calories closest to **1000** per 1, 2 and 3 servings. I know that you cannot use $min operator the way i did below, but it is just there to give an idea.

```
[
    {
      $project: {
        recipe: "$$ROOT",
        "caloriesInOneServing": "$calories",
        "caloriesInTwoServings": {$multiply: ["$calories", 2.0]},
        "caloriesInThereServings": {$multiply: ["$calories", 3.0]}
      }
    },
    {
       $project: {
        recipe: 1,
        "caloriesInOneServingDiff": {$subtract: ["$caloriesInOneServing", 1000],
        "caloriesInTwoServingsDiff": {$subtract: ["$caloriesInTwoServings", 1000],
        "caloriesInThereServingsDiff": {$subtract: ["$caloriesInThereServings", 1000]
      }
    },
    {
       $project: {
        recipe: 1,
        //how do i find the min value among given fields?
        minDiff: {$min: [$caloriesInOneServingDiff, caloriesInTwoServingsDiff, caloriesInThereServingsDiff]
      }
    },
    {
       $sort: { minDiff: -1 }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You will be better served if you can show sample document with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a conditional subtraction:

```
[
    {
      $project: {
        recipe: "$$ROOT",
        "caloriesInOneServing": "$calories",
        "caloriesInTwoServings": {$multiply: ["$calories", 2.0]},
        "caloriesInThereServings": {$multiply: ["$calories", 3.0]}
      }
    },
    {
       $project: {
        recipe: 1,
        "caloriesInOneServingDiff": {$cond: [
              { $lt: ['$caloriesInOneServing', 1000] },
              { $subtract: [1000, '$caloriesInOneServing'] }, 
              { $subtract: ['$caloriesInOneServing', 1000] }
            ]},
        "caloriesInTwoServingsDiff": {$cond: [
              { $lt: ['$caloriesInTwoServings', 1000] },
              { $subtract: [1000, '$caloriesInTwoServings'] }, 
              { $subtract: ['$caloriesInTwoServings', 1000] }
            ]},
        "caloriesInThereServingsDiff": {$cond: [
              { $lt: ['$caloriesInThereServings', 1000] },
              { $subtract: [1000, '$caloriesInThereServings'] }, 
              { $subtract: ['$caloriesInThereServings', 1000] }
            ]}
      }
    },
    {
       $project: {
        recipe: 1,
        minDiff: {$min: [$caloriesInOneServingDiff, caloriesInTwoServingsDiff, caloriesInThereServingsDiff]
      }
    },
    {
       $sort: { minDiff: -1 }
    }
  ]
```

Example:

```
calories = 300
x2 = 600
x3 = 900
```

after conditional subtraction:

```
caloriesDiff = 700
x2Diff = 400
x3Diff = 100
```

min = x3 which is closest to 1000

Comment: Great about $cond, but what about $min, afaik you can use it only wit h $group aggregation and NOT with $project. Isn't it?

Comment: @Dziamid Ah right, forgot about that. Gotta run, but I think that since Mongo runs on a V8 JS engine it should have access to the `Math` object which has a `min()` function. Since `$project` takes an expression you should be able to use that _I think_. If not, Ill post a solution when i get back.

Comment: Math.min wouldn't work because we are not passing any functions to the aggregate method, aggregation framework doesn't allow this.